# How to pass values from view.py to index.html in Django?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have all these variables in my view.py on Django.
And I want to put in on the index.html

```py
def current_database(request):
    contador = Post.objects.count()
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    mydb = myclient["prueba2"]
    mycol = mydb["miapp_post"]
    template = loader.get_template('miapp/index.html')

    for x in mycol.find():
        dominio = x['dominio']
        porcentaje_movil = x['porcentaje_movil']
        orportunidades_movil = x['orportunidades_movil']
        diagnosticos_movil = x['diagnosticos_movil']
        porcentaje_ordenador = x['porcentaje_ordenador']
        oportunidades_ordenador = x['oportunidades_ordenador']
        diagnosticos_ordenador = x['diagnosticos_ordenador']
        return HttpResponse(template.render(dominio, porcentaje_movil, orportunidades_movil, diagnosticos_movil, porcentaje_ordenador, oportunidades_ordenador, diagnosticos_ordenador))
```

When i go to my index.html all go fine the conecction its fine, no problem with that, but for exmple y put:

```py
<p>Dominio: {{ dominio }}</p>
```

or

```py
<p>Dominio: {% dominio %}</p>
```

and I always get and error and i dont know how to pass these values to mi html.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: This isn't at all how you render templates in Django. Have you done the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Just return the template like
`return render(request,'miapp/index.html',{'data': dominio})`
and access it in HTML using `{{ data }}`. Don't forget to import render function using `from django.shortcuts import render`

Answer (score 0):

Solve, I made this:

```
def current_database(request):
    contador = Post.objects.count()
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    mydb = myclient["prueba2"]
    mycol = mydb["miapp_post"]
    template = loader.get_template('miapp/index.html')

    for x in mycol.find():
        dominio = x['dominio']
        porcentaje_movil = x['porcentaje_movil']
        orportunidades_movil = x['orportunidades_movil']
        diagnosticos_movil = x['diagnosticos_movil']
        porcentaje_ordenador = x['porcentaje_ordenador']
        oportunidades_ordenador = x['oportunidades_ordenador']
        diagnosticos_ordenador = x['diagnosticos_ordenador']
        context = {
            'dominio': dominio,
            'porcentaje_movil': porcentaje_movil,
            'orportunidades_movil': orportunidades_movil,
            'diagnosticos_movil': diagnosticos_movil,
            'porcentaje_ordenador': porcentaje_ordenador,
            'oportunidades_ordenador': oportunidades_ordenador,
            'diagnosticos_ordenador': diagnosticos_ordenador,
        }
        return render(request, 'miapp/index.html', context)
```

and in the html I just put that:

```py
<p>Dominio: {{ dominio }}</p>
```

Comment: This is all pointless. Just do `return render(request, 'miapp/index.html', x)`. Also why have a for loop at all if you're going to return after the first iteration? Surely you should do `x = mycol.find_one()` and remove the loop altogether. And, finally, you're not using `template` any more so remove that line.

Comment: and for example if i want to return multiples variables but with return i stop the loop, and i dont know how to send to the html first the context of the first loop and then the context of the second loop